# flask-sqlalchemy join nested child tables to one parent (+Marshmallow)

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm learning Flask and SQLAlchemy, and I can find a lot of useful stuff. However I'm stuck with the query for joining multiple tables.

> First

I have this setup in relations:

```
-Parent
--Child
----sibling1
----sibling2
```

If I perform in my SQL browser the search:

```
 Select * from sibling1, sibling2 join(select * from child join(select * from Parent))
```

This gives me the result of binding it all together. At least no error...

But I can't find any information on how to translate this inside the Flask-SQLAlchemy. (I was able to do so for only sibling1,child and parent).

> Secondary:

And :-) How can I provide these results in Marshmallow and show the contents instead of just the table_key_id?
Useful sources can help, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this should be a comment, but its hard to put code in that box lol.

If you are using flask-sqlalchemy you can do joins, etc.

Here's an example joins query we use:

```py
projects = (
        db.session.query()
        .select_from(Project)
        .join(User, User.id == Project.owner_id)
        .join(Task, Task.project_id == Project.id)
        .filter(User.id == current_user.id)
        .add_columns(Project.name, Project.id, func.count(Task.id))
        .group_by(Project.name, Project.id)
        .all()
    )
```

You can use `outerjoin` in place of `join` as `join` defaults to inner join.

Comment: Ok, I understood this and tried this. Howver, in SQLITE browser I can see the relationship as ok. But then I got an error on a column join name. 'Ambiguous colomn name'. I guess that the name does not exist in my 'parent' table. But, as I understood from relationships in sqlalchemy, there is no column, but it acts as a pseudo background...

Comment: How does your model look?

Comment: - There was indeed an error in my understanding. Still learning, no my experience here. More a netorking guy :-). But, now it works. I did: Parent has a relationship to child. Child has a column with foreignkey to parent. The child has also a relationship to the third table(sibling). The sibling has only a column with foreignkey to the 'child' table. So this follows what I initially wrote.